# on-click facebook login by php

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

i have a project that have option to log in with facebook.
but this option only work for the admin of the site 
whenever any other user want to log in the site a form will appear and ask some info. if full fill the form and click register it shows a error message.
Now i want to remove the form part from the website and want onclick login for all user. here is the link of the site 
https://dev.metarank.com/

please help me to find the solution

thanks in advance

Comment: hello i want to remove the registration page that appear after clck on sign in with face book
and my problem is Admin can access the website when he click on sign in with face book but no others can access directly .for others user registration form window shown
but i want direct login for all

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong to create a Facebook login button you need to create an app to obtain api keys, right?

If it is the case the problem could be the following:

After testing the login button you have to make the app publicly available by passing a review process from Facebook, and then anyone will be able to login to your website with a Facebook account.

As said: this is the process for standard apps, at the moment I am not sure at all about if it is exactly the same process for logins.

Comment: hello 
my apps is public
but still same problem.. only admin can get access directly but no other user can access directly the sites .